# NextJS: как динамически добавить ссылку к тексту?

Tags: reactjs, nextjs, next.js

Извините, если не верно сформулировал вопрос. Суть задачи такая: у меня есть некий компонент, где подставляется текст в лейбл

```
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: row.label}}></div>
```

Как я могу, если надо, добавить еще ссылку в этот лейбл? Что бы получилось так

```
 <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: row.label + <Link href={'/privacy-agree'}><a>{t('политикой конфиденциальности')}</a></Link>}}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так:

```
<div>
  <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: row.label}}></span>
  <Link href={'/privacy-agree'}><a>{t('политикой конфиденциальности')}</a></Link>
</div>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @p1uton мне нужно, что бы ссылка была в span